# HEROKU Application Err - Application error An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm looking a solution for my stupid problems.
I use Heroku to deployed my application. After I linked to github,I got this error when open my application:

> Application error An error occurred in the application and your page
>   could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs
>   for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
>   heroku logs --tail

I tried to research the solution but nothing worked.
My config in app.js

```
port = process.env.PORT || config.__port_server,
app.listen(port)
```

thank you

Comment: "I tried to research the solution but nothing worked." Did you try what the error message says to do, "If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command heroku logs --tail"?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Please consider [posting an answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and then accepting it so other users can benefit in the future.